# How to set a timeout for establishing a connection using net.Dialer?

Tags: go

For example if the server does not respond for more than 3 seconds, I neet to get an error or something specific.
I search everything but only see the lifetime of the connection (net.Dialer.Timeout / net.Dialer.Deadline) but neet to limit limit exactly the **establishing** time.

Now my code like

```
dialer := net.Dialer{LocalAddr: net.TCPAddr{IP:"192.168.1.68", Port:35030}}
conn, err := tls.DialWithDialer(dialer, "tcp", "123.45.67.89", &tls.Config{...})
```

Thanks!

Comment: That is the time to establish the connection, see [`net.DialTimeout`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#DialTimeout) or [`Dialer.DialContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Dialer.DialContext). Have you tried setting `Timeout` or `Deadline`?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, first, you can simply [set the Timeout field](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Dialer.Timeout) of the `net.Dialer`, it does what you want:

> // Timeout is the maximum amount of time a dial will wait for
> a connect to complete. If Deadline is also set, it may fail
> earlier.

```
timeout := time.Millisecond*3000

dialer := net.Dialer{Timeout: timeout, LocalAddr: net.TCPAddr{IP:"192.168.1.68", Port:35030}}
conn, err := tls.DialWithDialer(&dialer, "tcp", "123.45.67.89", &tls.Config{...})
```

There are some others solutions, like using `net.DialTimeout`, [Dialer.DialContext](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Dialer.DialContext) and setting the timeout for the context you are passing:

```
timeout := time.Millisecond*3000

ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
conn , err := dialer.DialContext(ctx, "tcp", "123.45.67.89:8000")
```

Comment: Thanks meshkati! I think I just cunfused 2 properties cause one of them was incorrectly used in my project.